# What is a Poison Dart attack?

Tags: attacks, ddos, terminology

From [The Forrester Wave™: DDoS Services Providers,
Q3 2015 report](http://www.imperva.com/docs/RPT_Forrester_Wave_DDoS_2015.pdf), (emphasis mine):

> **Attack types defended**
>
> CGI request, denial of capability,
>   diluted low rate degrading, direct,
>   DNS request attack via fast DNS,
>   high-rate disruptive, hybrid attack,
>   ICMP attack, isotropic attack traf­c
>   distribution, land attack, nonisotropic
>   attack traf­c distribution,
>   ping of death, reector, TCP reset,
>   TCP SYN ooding, teardrop attack,
>   UDP ooding, varied rate, highly
>   volumetric AppSec, **poison dart**,
>   slow POST, and origin error attacks

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reference on the web to this class of attack outside of Akamai marketing materials. Have you tried asking them what they mean by it?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a partially meaningless list of *information security buzzwords*.

While some terms exist in an infosec context (e.g. [TCP SYN Flooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood)), others are uncommon or ridiculously vague ("Hybrid Attack", "Varied Rate"). As it mixes arbitrary levels of precision and non-established expressions, the entire list seems inappropriate for a comprehensive overview of different attack types and I suggest to not further question the term **poison dart**, since it will likely not be understood in the security community.

If you are interested in generating security buzzwords yourself, have a look at a [this blogpost](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/on-security-buzzwords/index.html). (The generator itself is unavailable at the time of writing.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are going to find an answer to this question definitively. I have searched quite a bit for this type of attack, including the Akamai website, and haven't found it anywhere other than:
http://accudatasystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/The_Forrester_Wave_DDoS_S.pdf

and

http://www.itogether.co.uk/2015/08/akamai-prolexic-vs-cloudflare-vs-check-point-ddos-protection-vs-corero-smartwall-appliance-v-incapsula-imperva/

Where it is only mentioned as a type of attack but not given detail as to how the attack occurs.

There are a lot of links that come up for ARP Poisoning and DNS Poisoning. This "Poison Dart" attack they reference could just be a catchy name they have given this type of attack. If you would like more info on those here are some helpful links.
http://www.arppoisoning.com/how-does-arp-poisoning-work/

and

http://www.networkworld.com/article/2277316/tech-primers/how-dns-cache-poisoning-works.html

Hope this helps.